# decode and encode nsmanagedobject

Tags: macos, swift3, pasteboard

good morning :)

i would like to use pasteboard with an nsmanagedobject.
This is my class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Persons)
public class Persons: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var secondName: String?

}
```

My ViewController:

```
var persons = [Persons]() // filled in another code part

override func viewDidLoad() {

     pboard.declareTypes(["MyType"],owner: nil)
     pboard.setData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: persons), forType: "MyType")     
}
```

App crashes with this logs:

```
2017-06-23 08:16:18.605141+0200 TableView-DragDrop[29133:3726505]
-[Persons encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000088f20 2017-06-23 08:16:18.606057+0200 TableView-DragDrop[29133:3726505] [General] -[Persons encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000088f20 2017-06-23 08:16:18.609989+0200 TableView-DragDrop[29133:3726505] [General] (     0   CoreFoundation      0x00007fffb9eae57b __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib    0x00007fffcf0f21da objc_exception_throw + 48     2   CoreFoundation       0x00007fffb9f2ef14 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb9e21c93
___forwarding___ + 1059     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb9e217e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   Foundation         0x00007fffbb8ae95a _encodeObject + 1241  6   Foundation                0x00007fffbb8aff0c -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 460     7   Foundation                          0x00007fffbb8ae95a
_encodeObject + 1241    8   Foundation                          0x00007fffbb8ea492 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 156     9   TableView-DragDrop                  0x0000000100003147
_TFC18TableView_DragDrop8SourceVC9tableViewfTCSo11NSTableView13writeRowsWithV10Foundation8IndexSet2toCSo12NSPasteboard_Sb
+ 583   10  TableView-DragDrop                  0x00000001000033bc _TToFC18TableView_DragDrop8SourceVC9tableViewfTCSo11NSTableView13writeRowsWithV10Foundation8IndexSet2toCSo12NSPasteboard_Sb
+ 108   11  AppKit                              0x00007fffb80d4109 -[NSTableView _sendDataSourceWriteDragDataWithIndexes:toPasteboard:] + 102   12  AppKit                              0x00007fffb80d4d06
-[NSTableView _performClassicDragOfIndexes:hitRow:event:] + 180     13  AppKit                              0x00007fffb7bf67b5 -[NSTableView
_performDragFromMouseDown:] + 468   14  AppKit                              0x00007fffb7bf4adf -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 735  15  AppKit         0x00007fffb821824f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting)
_handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6341   16  AppKit                              0x00007fffb8214a6c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting)
_reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 1942    17  AppKit                              0x00007fffb8213f0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541     18  AppKit                              0x00007fffb8098681
-[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145     19  AppKit                              0x00007fffb7913427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002  20  AppKit             0x00007fffb78dde0e NSApplicationMain + 1237  21  TableView-DragDrop    0x00000001000058ad main + 13  22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffcf9d3235 start + 1    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3 ) 2017-06-23 08:16:18.611031+0200 TableView-DragDrop[29133:3726505] *** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated without having had
-finishEncoding called on it.
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: can you clear the question that what you exactly want to do?

Comment: final result: two tableviews, drag and drop from first tableview to second tableview with pasteboard. and i think, i have to convert my persons "array" to data to do this.